# puppeteer cluster начинает зависать при 20 потоках

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Использую puppeteer cluster для автоматизации действий на сайте, нужно работать с сайтом одновременно с разных аккаунтов, поэтому для многопоточности использую именно puppeteer cluster.

Устройство у меня достаточно мощное, но вот если запускать одновременно 20 или более потоков - браузера (puppeteer) начинают тормозить сильно, как будто скорость интернета стала очень медленной.  из-за чего приложение падает, так как не удается дождаться селекторов.

Есть ли какие то способы оптимизировать приложение с puppeteer cluster?

У меня скрипт достаточно простой, заходит на страницу, вводит данные для авторизации и постоянно находится на определенной странице, периодически кликая по определенным кнопкам.

PS. Запускаю в безголовом режиме.

Comment: нужно использовать кэширование данных и сохранять состояние браузера между запросами, чтобы уменьшить необходимость повторно загружать страницы

Answer (score -1):

Это не совсем ответ, а просто рекомендации.
Есть несколько способов оптимизировать приложение с puppeteer cluster:

- Использовать безголовый режим для запуска браузера, как вы это уже делаете, это может уменьшить нагрузку на ресурсы компьютера.
- Уменьшить количество одновременно запущенных потоков до максимально возможного, которое не вызывает торможения.

  - Начните с небольшого количества потоков, например, 2-4, и наблюдайте за производительностью приложения.
  - Постепенно увеличивайте количество потоков, например, на 2-4 за раз, и продолжайте наблюдать за производительностью.
  - Когда вы заметите снижение производительности или торможение, вернитесь к предыдущему количеству потоков и продолжайте работать с ним.
  - Продолжайте экспериментировать с количеством потоков до тех пор, пока вы не найдете оптимальное количество, которое не вызывает торможения и обеспечивает достаточную производительность
- Использовать кэширование данных и сохранять состояние браузера между запросами, чтобы уменьшить необходимость повторно загружать страницы. Можете использовать модуль Node.js для кэширования данных, как `lru-cache` или `node-cache`. Это позволит вам сохранять данные в кэше и использовать их в следующем запросе, если они доступны, вместо того, чтобы заново загружать их с сайта.
- Вы можете использовать какой-то другой инструмент))